# Spark Join Best Match Efficiency Issues

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have 2 DataFrames:

- `df_1` with around 500 Million records and ~100 columns
- `df_2` with ~50 million records and 4 columns

I need to left join `df_1` with `df_2` with an exact match on two of the columns and a best match on the third.  By best match i mean there is a one:many relationship from left to right however i only want to receive the best match on the right hand side in terms of length.

e.g.

```
# df_1
col1    col2    col3
---------------------------
a       b       abcde
```

```
# df_2
col1    col2    col3    col4
-------------------------------
a       b       a       90
a       b       ab      100
a       b       abc     150
a       c       abc     90
```

So the desired result of the join when i match `col1` and `col2` exactly and `col3` on the best match of the contained strings is:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
-------------------------------
a       b       abcde   150
```

Some points working against me here:

- The lengths of `col3` on the left hand side are genearlly between 10 and 15 characters, on the right hand side can vary from 1 character to 9 characters
- Both `df_1` and `df_2` are similarly skewed on `col3`

While I have got this working I am getting **terrible performance**.

I have tried the following solutions and am still not getting anywhere:

- broadcasting `df_2` (fell over as too large to broadcast)
- join exactly on `col1` and `col1` and use `like` on `col3` (terrible)
- explode out the values on `col3` in `df_2` to try and fight skew (improvement but still slow)
- persist data and loop through each length in the right hand side and join exactly on the concatenation of `col1`, `col2` and `col3` (where the concatenation of the left hand side is a substring of `col3`) (improvement but still slow)

What is the most performant way to do this join using spark?

Comment: So, in df1 you need a bigger string & from df2 you need the largest number or you need the larger concatenated & larger number from both the dataframes ??

Comment: So in df1 i have a string in col3 that i need to find the longest match for in d2 col3 to bring bring back col4

Comment: can you please explain a bit more

Comment: Essentially df1 is the main output of my model, df2 is a lookup table to enable me to bring back `col4`  for later use by joining on the other 3 columns. col 3 has variable lengths (one per row) and i need to bring back the corresponding col4 for the match with the longest value in col3

Comment: Are you selecting third row on the basis of col_4  value, since it is highest among other a and b combination (150)?

Comment: Hi Nikki,  no it is on the basis of `df1.col1 = df2.col1`, `df1.col2=df2.col2` and `df1.col3.startswith(df2.col3)`

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to reduce the data size before joining(we cannot eradicate joining). We can reduce as below:

First, loading data

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> df1.show
+---+---+-----+
| c1| c2|   c3|
+---+---+-----+
|  a|  b|abcde|
|  c|  d|   fd|
+---+---+-----+

scala> df2.show
+---+---+----+---+
| c1| c2|  c3| c4|
+---+---+----+---+
|  a|  b|   a| 90|
|  a|  b| abd|100|
|  a|  b|abcd|150|
|  c|  d|wewe| 79|
+---+---+----+---+
```

Now we need to reduce the size of df2 before joining(this will reduce the time take for joining as the data size is less compared) using window function and finding out the max of both the columns

```
scala> df2.withColumn("len", length($"c3")).withColumn("res", row_number().over(wind1)).filter($"res" === 1).withColumn("res2", row_number().over(wind2)).filter($"res2"=== 1).select("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4").show()
+---+---+----+---+
| c1| c2|  c3| c4|
+---+---+----+---+
|  c|  d|wewe| 79|
|  a|  b|abcd|150|
+---+---+----+---+
```

things to try :

1> You can join this reduced dataframes and apply the logic you are using

2> Try doing union `df1.withColumn("c4", lit(0)).union(df2)` and then apply the above logic.

Hope this helps